# Get source url for image stored in Bluemix Object Storage container using Node.js app

Tags: node.js, npm, ibm-cloud, object-storage

I have an Object Storage instance on Bluemix where I am storing images in the container. I need a source url for the images stored there so that I can use that image. To do this, I'm thinking of creating a Node.js app so that I will write a post call where I'll pass image name present in Object Storage as request, so that it will give me the image url as response.
 Is this possible or not? If possible, can anyone suggest whether there are any npm modules which do this functionality? If not, are there any other suggestions to get the url of image?

Any help is appreciated..Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

start the server by command `node app.js` also u need package `pkgcloud` to perform this operation. You can get the object storage credentials simply by creating a key on IBM console inside Storage module.
inside `app.js` insert a new route for download

```
var  objectStorageHandler = require("./lib/objectStorageHandler.js");
```

app.get('/download', function(req, res) {

```
(new objectStorageHandler()).download('YourContainerName', 'imagenamewithextension',function(download){
    console.log(res);
    download.pipe(res);
});
```

});

Inside Lib folder create a module with name `objectStorageHandler.js`

Inside `objectStorageHandler.js` write code

```
var pkgcloud = require('pkgcloud');
```

var objectStorageHandler = function(){

}

```
objectStorageHandler.prototype.download =  function(container, file,callback)
{
    var config = {
        provider: 'openstack',
        useServiceCatalog: true,
        useInternal: false,
        keystoneAuthVersion: 'v3',
        authUrl: 'https://identity.open.softlayer.com',
        tenantId: 'YOURPROJECTID',    //projectId from credentials
        domainId: 'YOURDOMAINID',
        username: 'YOURUSRNAME',
        password: 'YOURPASSWORD',
        region: 'dallas'   //dallas or london region
    };

var client = pkgcloud.storage.createClient(config);
client.auth(function (error) {
    if(error) {
        console.error("Authorization error for storage client (pkgcloud): ", error);
    }
    else {
        var request = client.download({
            container: container,
            remote: file
        });

        callback(request);
    }
});
```

}

module.exports = objectStorageHandler;

after server started lets assume at port 3000 simply call localhost:3000/download that will download the image, we can also pass image name in parameters to download images dynamically.

Comment: ..Thanks but is it possible a create a src url to that image?